# how to retrieve multiple images got from server and show them in UIImageView with swipe

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

how to add swipe gesture for multiple images retrieved from server.
i get str=@"but1.jpg,but2.jpg" from server.how to show both these images stored in string with swipe.
for single image showing from server I am getting response from server based on key "image_names" ,am storing it in string.my code is as below

```
url=@"http:..........";
str=[dict1 valueForKey:@"image_names"];
if (str!=nil) {
strImg=[url stringByAppendingString:str];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strImg]];
    if ( data == nil )
        return;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithData: data];
        imgView.image=img;
    });


});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not getting what exactly you question is but you can add swipe gesture to any image as below lines of code.

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeftGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeftGesture:)];
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRightGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRightGesture:)];

 [swipeLeftGesture setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
 [swipeRightGesture setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];

// Adding the both the swipe gesture to UIImageview
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeftGesture];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRightGesture];
```